# Why is 'no connection' error appearing while accessing Google Play store?

Tags: sync, google, clock

I have this common, annoying problem while trying to access Google Play Store from my phone. It just shows 'no connection', and won't load, even though the internet access is surely working. The suspected cause is a synchronization error of my Google account, likely due to incorrect time settings (it's reported while running WhatsApp for example). Here's what I've done so far:

1. Set the time automatically
2. Manually set the time, without using the network
3. Clearing cache of Google Play store application
4. Reinstalling Google Play store manually using .apk
5. Logging out and back in with my Google account
6. Rooting the phone and using ClockSync app to set the time
7. Doing a factory reset of my device
8. Making sure Freedom application is not installed

I'm slowly running out of ideas...if anyone has the smallest hint, I'll be really grateful.